# search for column with specific suffix, and optional leading zeros

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Assume that I have 1234. I want a query to select all columns that match:

```
1234
01234
001234
0001234
...
```

How can I do that in SQLite?

Comment: Can't understand your question even.

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia, I have a search box and user has entered 1234. I want to select rows that one of their columns match 1234 or 01234 or 001234 or ...

Comment: that would be a postfix / suffix ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to convert the string into a number:

```
SELECT ... WHERE CAST(Column AS NUMBER) = 1234
```

However, this also allows leading spaces, or `.0` floating-point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'like' query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field like '%1234%'
```

Comment: I want only 0 before entered text. % returns all characters.